# Package dependencies cannot be resolved when installing totem

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, software-sources, totem

Package dependencies cannot be resolved when installing totem and I get this in details:

```
totem: Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
       Depends: libnautilus-extension1a (>= 1:2.91) but 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu8 is to be installed
       Depends: libtotem0 (>= 3.10.1-1ubuntu4) but 3.10.1-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
       Depends: totem-common (= 3.10.1-1ubuntu4) but 3.10.1-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

I have found out that my problem is libtotem0. I have an old version installed. When I mark it in Synaptic for upgrade and Apply, it says that I have broken packages. How can I find out which ones are broken and fix them?

Here is my sources.list. Strange it says saucy, but I installed trusty.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
## deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
# deb-src http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
```

Comment: Didn't you mess with sources.list ? Can you show your sources.list and ppa's added ?

Comment: also, i noticed when i run upgrade in terminal i get this:The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gstreamer1.0-clutter libcheese-gtk23 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-2.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libtotem0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
yaro014 - i will google ppas and sources.list and try to find them and post them here.

Comment: here is my sources.list.  it say saucy but i ugrade to trusty??

Comment: i have found out that my problem is libtotem0. Ihave an old version installed.  When I mark it in synaptic for upgrade and apply it says that i have broken packages.  How can i findout whibh ones are broken and fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with installing all the dependencies of [Totem](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/totem),

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl12 libdbus-glib-1-2 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnautilus-extension1a libpango1.0-0 plparser17 libtotem0 libtotem0 libx11-6python totem-common
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` or `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`? They can tell you which packages are broken and automatically fix them for you.
Also, you could try uninstalling libtotem0 and reinstalling it.